# How to convert PNG image to GIF in Android programatically

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am working an app in which I want to convert images from png format to gif format please help me or some suggestion for that

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Gif encoder` class to achieve that.
For example, you could use https://github.com/nbadal/android-gif-encoder/blob/master/GifEncoder.java

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
  AnimatedGifEncoder encoder = new AnimatedGifEncoder();
  encoder.start(bos);
  encoder.addFrame(image);
  encoder.finish();
  byte[] array = bos.toByteArray();

  // Save to file
  File output = new File("output.gif");
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(output.getPath());
  fos.write(array);
  fos.close();
```